# How to download an MP3 file from a website that prevents direct download link?

Tags: javascript, http, request, httprequest, mp3

How do you download the MP3 file from this website?

https://www.audiobookcup.com/race-the-sands-a-novel-audiobook/

I've tried inspect element and found the .mp3 file https://videos3.audiobookx.com/1421-MP3/BK_HARP_010531.mp3

However, when I try directly downloading it, I get an unauthorized message

Would really appreciate the help! For some reason, the audiobookcup site refreshes every 10  minutes while I'm listening, which makes it really hard to find my place again. Having a way to download the file would mean a lot!

Comment: Questions for piracy aren't appropriate here.  If you have a legitimate need to access this, talk to the folks who run this site for proper access.

Answer (score 5):

When you're on the web page, open the DevTools with <kbd>F12</kbd> then copy/paste this code in the console:

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "https://videos3.audiobookx.com/1421-MP3/BK_HARP_010531.mp3";
link.download = 'some-file-name.mp3';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

You can replace `'some-file-name.mp3'` with the name you want.

Comment: Hi @guerric-p I tried running the code in the console on the website!

I waited 5 minutes, but no file got downloaded. Could I be missing something?

Comment: @maddie I've updated my answer with a simpler solution that allows to download directly without loading the file in memory

Comment: Brilliant answer